# IBM Worklight 6.0 - jQuery Mobile pageshow event not triggered

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I got an issue in my Worklight project with jQuery Mobile 1.3.0.

Pages are well displayed, but `pageshow` events are not triggered.
The web console logs 2 javascript errors when page is initialized:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand profile @ http://myhost:10080/myProject/apps/services/preview/InfoCenter/common/0/default/wlclient/js/worklight.js:2569

TypeError: ajaxRequest is undefined @ http://myhost:10080/myProject/apps/services/preview/InfoCenter/common/0/default/wlclient/js/wlclient.js:2460
```

Comment: ptitjuju69, is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It would've been better had you provided some code snippets from your app...

Using this code, `pageshow` worked OK for me:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#page2", function(event) {
        alert("page 2 loaded");
    });
}
```

When my Worklight 6.1-based jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 app changes a page using `changePage`, the above is executed and an alert is displayed. I tested it in the Worklight Console MBS.

[Here's a sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f0xr9ogp4ofuqs/JQM_multipage_changePage_pageshow.zip).